# ASPxTextbox - masking, prompt always at last or first character

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, client-side

I have an aspxtextbox e.g

```
  <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" Width="150">
                            <MaskSettings Mask="00000" ErrorText="Please input missing symbols" />
                            <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" />
                        </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

How can I modify it so that when the user goes to the textbox, it will always position the cursor at index 0, or the last entered character?

Thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by handling the editor's client side GotFocus event handler.  Here is some sample code:

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" Width="150">
                    <MaskSettings Mask="00000" ErrorText="Please input missing symbols" />
                    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" />
                    <ClientSideEvents GotFocus="
                    function(s,e) {
                        var editorValue = s.GetValue();
                        if(editorValue)
                            s.SetCaretPosition(editorValue.toString().length);
                    }" />
                </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```